# Issue with Embedded Signing Client URL s

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the Docusign SOAP API to embed a docusign template in a Visualforce page. When the document is signed I would like to redirect to another page. I am using the ClientURL but it doesn't seem to be working. When I sign the document and hit Finish, I get the Please wait modal and it just stays there. Any idea what the issue could be? Code snippet is included below. Let me know if you need additional information. Thanks!

```
DocuSignAPI.RequestRecipientTokenClientURLs clientURLs = new DocuSignAPI.RequestRecipientTokenClientURLs();
clientURLs.OnSigningComplete = 'https://zzz-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/00QG000000w0ZsaMAE' + '/' + '&event=OnSigningComplete&envelopeid=' + envelopeID;
    try {
        token = dsApiSend.RequestRecipientToken(envelopeId, recipient.captiveinfo.ClientUserId, recipient.UserName, recipient.Email, assert,clientURLs);
    }  catch ( CalloutException e) {
        System.debug('Exception - ' + e );
        errMsg = 'Exception - ' + e;
        return '';    //TODO: send to error landing place
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's an accessible URL you are passing?  As a test what happens if you simply try to redirect to www.google.com?

Comment: I tried redirecting to google but that doesn't work either. I get this error.                                                                                                         Firefox can't find the server at www.google.com&event=onsigningcomplete&envelopeid=0eb0c037-b3b2-4b9f-86d5-bae46af8d227.

Comment: I get the 'Please Wait' after clicking Confirm Signing. I tried Chrome version 43.0.2357.65 and Firefox version 33.1. I tried disabling the Winter Signing Feature but still see the same issue.

Comment: Two things I suggest- 1) follow the Embedded Signing examples in the [open source SOAP SDK on GitHub](https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-eSignature-SDK) for a proper example of how it works.  2) capture the raw SOAP XML that you're code is creating and inspect it (you can do this through Report Logging feature in your account preferences)